# Marcação de strings e retorno de valor

Tags: c, string

Eis o meu programa, preciso cadastrar até 100 produtos, cada produto está disponíveis em 5 lojas e preciso dizer a quantidade vendida de cada produto em cada uma das 5 lojas. Vou ter uma menu que terá opção de cadastramento, media de venda de cada uma das lojas, media de venda de cada produto e o produto mais vendido de cada loja.

O problema maior que estou enfrentando é o seguinte: se o produto de maior venda estiver no `vetor[5]` da loja 1, como dizer o nome desse produto?

**Código:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>

#define tamanho_nome 50
#define quantidade_produtos 100

int main(){

char nome_produto[quantidade_produtos][tamanho_nome];
int loja1[quantidade_produtos];
int loja2[quantidade_produtos];
int loja3[quantidade_produtos];
int loja4[quantidade_produtos];
int loja5[quantidade_produtos];
int quantidade_cadastrada=0,i,opcao,posicao=0;
float medialoja1=0;
float medialoja2=0;
float medialoja3=0;
float medialoja4=0;
float medialoja5=0;
float media_venda_cada_produto=0;
int maior_vendal1=0;
int maior_vendal2=0;
int maior_vendal3=0;
int maior_vendal4=0;
int maior_vendal5=0;

do{
system("CLS");
printf("1-Cadastrar novo produto: \n");
printf("2-Media venda de cada loja: \n");
printf("3-Media de venda de cada produto : \n");
printf("4- Produto mais vendido de cada loja: \n");
printf("5-Sair: \n");
scanf("%d",&opcao);
system("CLS");
fflush(stdin);
if(opcao==5){
    break;
}

switch(opcao){

case 1: printf("Digite o nome do produto: \n");
scanf("%[^\n]",&nome_produto[posicao]);

printf("Digite a quantidade vendida na Loja 1: \n");
scanf("%d",&loja1[posicao]);
printf("Digite a quantidade vendida na Loja 2: \n");
scanf("%d",&loja2[posicao]);
printf("Digite a quantidade vendida na Loja 3: \n");
scanf("%d",&loja3[posicao]);
printf("Digite a quantidade vendida na Loja 4: \n");
scanf("%d",&loja4[posicao]);
printf("Digite a quantidade vendida na Loja 5: \n");
scanf("%d",&loja5[posicao]);
posicao++;
system("PAUSE");
system("cls");
break;

case 2: for(i=0;i<posicao;i++){
medialoja1+=loja1[i];
medialoja2+=loja2[i];
medialoja3+=loja3[i];
medialoja4+=loja4[i];
medialoja5+=loja5[i];
}
medialoja1=medialoja1/posicao;
medialoja2=medialoja2/posicao;
medialoja3=medialoja3/posicao;
medialoja4=medialoja4/posicao;
medialoja5=medialoja5/posicao;

printf("\nA loja 1 vendeu em media %2.f ",medialoja1);
printf("\nA loja 2 vendeu em media %2.f ",medialoja2);
printf("\nA loja 3 vendeu em media %2.f ",medialoja3);
printf("\nA loja 4 vendeu em media %2.f ",medialoja4);
printf("\nA loja 5 vendeu em media %2.f ",medialoja5);
system("PAUSE");
system("CLS");
break;

case 3: for(i=0;i<posicao;i++){
media_venda_cada_produto=loja1[i]+loja2[i]+loja3[i]+loja4[i]+loja5[i];
media_venda_cada_produto=media_venda_cada_produto/5;
printf("%s vendeu %2.f \n",nome_produto[i],media_venda_cada_produto);
}
system("PAUSE");
system("CLS");
break;

case 4:
  maior_vendal1=loja1[0];
  maior_vendal2=loja2[0];
  maior_vendal3=loja3[0];
  maior_vendal4=loja4[0];
  maior_vendal5=loja5[0];

  for(i=0;i<posicao;i++){

    if(loja1[i]>maior_vendal1){
        maior_vendal1=loja1[i];
    }
     if(loja2[i]>maior_vendal2){
        maior_vendal2=loja2[i];
    }
     if(loja3[i]>maior_vendal3){
        maior_vendal3=loja3[i];
    }
     if(loja4[i]>maior_vendal4){
        maior_vendal4=loja4[i];
    }
     if(loja5[i]>maior_vendal5){
        maior_vendal5=loja5[i];
    }
  }

   for(i=0;i<posicao;i++){
    if(maior_vendal1==loja1[i]){
    printf("\nProduto mais vendido da loja1 e o %s\n",nome_produto[i]);
    }
    if(maior_vendal2==loja2[i]){
   printf("\nProduto mais vendido da loja2 e o %s\n",nome_produto[i]);
    }

    if(maior_vendal3==loja3[i]){
    printf("\nProduto mais vendido da loja3 e o %s\n",nome_produto[i]);
    }

    if(maior_vendal4==loja4[i]){
 printf("\nProduto mais vendido da loja4 e o %s\n",nome_produto[i]);
    }

    if(maior_vendal5==loja5[i]){
  printf("\nProduto mais vendido da loja5 e o %s\n",nome_produto[i]);
    }
   }



    system("PAUSE");
    system("CLS");
    break;

    default: printf("Voce digitou uma opcao invalida: \n");
    system("PAUSE");
    system("CLS");
    }
  }
while(opcao!=5000);
}
```

Código rodando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/zFMqQ5).

Comment: o link do ideone não está funcionando aqui...

Comment: as 5 lojas possuem os 100 produtos ou cada uma pode ou não ter um produto?

Comment: não e sim kkk, se eu cadastrar um produto tenho que informar a quantidade vendida desse produto em cada uma das 5 lojas (as 5 tem que ter o mesmo produto) , mesmo que seja 0 vendidos @Leila

Comment: vou desistir kk da pergunta , só faço pergunta idiota :s

Comment: pera, eu estou vendo aqui, tem uns erros no código e está incompleto, certo? vou mandar o que corrigi e já penso na pergunta em si

Answer (score 2):

Bom, tem alguns erros no código, como `scanf("%d", &loja1);`

Por ser vetor já é um ponteiro para int, então colocar o `&` faz com que a variável fique do tipo `**int`, então o certo é usar sem o `&` nesse caso:  `scanf("%d", loja1);`

Você fez esse `"do-if"`, se é que isso existe, e não entendi por que.

```
do{
    printf("O que deseja saber?: \n");
    printf("1-Cadastrar um novo produto ?: \n 2-Media de venda das lojas ?: \n 3-Media de venda dos produtos ?: \n 4-Produto mais vendido de cada uma das lojas ?: \n 5-Sair \n");
    scanf("%d",&opcao);

    if(opcao==5){
        break;
    }
```

Mudei para esse `do-while`:

```
do{
        printf("O que deseja saber?: \n");
        printf("1-Cadastrar um novo produto ?: \n 2-Media de venda das lojas ?: \n 3-Media de venda dos produtos ?: \n 4-Produto mais vendido de cada uma das lojas ?: \n 5-Sair \n");
        scanf("%d",&opcao);

}while(opcao != 5);
```

O `do-while` tem significado "faça isso enquanto a condição for verdadeira", aí nesse caso quando a opção escolhida for 5, a condição vai ficar falsa e vai sair do while.

Com essas correções ficou assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#define quantidade_produtos 100
#define tamanho_nome 100
#define quantidade_vendida 100

int main(){

    int produtos=0,opcao;
    float medialoja1=0,medialoja2=0,medialoja3=0,medialoja4=0,medialoja5=0;
    char nome_produto[quantidade_produtos][tamanho_nome];
    int loja1[quantidade_produtos],loja2[quantidade_produtos];
    int loja3[quantidade_produtos] ,loja4[quantidade_produtos];
    int loja5[quantidade_produtos];

    do{
        printf("O que deseja saber?: \n");
        printf("1-Cadastrar um novo produto ?: \n 2-Media de venda das lojas ?: \n 3-Media de venda dos produtos ?: \n 4-Produto mais vendido de cada uma das lojas ?: \n 5-Sair \n");
        scanf("%d",&opcao);

    }while(opcao != 5); 

    fflush(stdin);
    switch(opcao){

        case 1: 
            printf("Qual o nome do produto?: \n");
            scanf("%[^\n]",nome_produto[produtos]);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Qual a quantidade vendida na loja 1 ?: \n");
            scanf("%d",loja1);
            printf("Qual a quantidade vendida na loja 2 ?: \n");
            scanf("%d",loja2);
            printf("Qual a quantidade vendida na loja 3 ?: \n");
            scanf("%d",loja3);
            printf("Qual a quantidade vendida na loja 4 ?: \n");
            scanf("%d",loja4);
            printf("Qual a quantidade vendida na loja 5 ?: \n");
            scanf("%d",loja5);
            produtos++;
            break;

        case 2: 
        for(int i=0;i<produtos; i++){
            medialoja1+=loja1[i];    
        }
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Sobre a pergunta em si, "se o produto de maior venda estiver no vetor[5] da loja 1, como dizer o nome desse produto?", me parece que a forma que você estruturou não ajuda. E tem algumas coisas que não entendi o propósito, por exemplo:

```
printf("Qual a quantidade vendida na loja 1 ?: \n");
scanf("%d",loja1);
```

Ao fazer isso, você coloca a quantidade na primeira posição do vetor apenas, o que não faz muito sentido. Se puder explicar melhor como você pensou posso tentar ajudar. Pesquisa sobre struct que talvez pode ser útil pra salvar o nome e a quantidade do produto no mesmo lugar.

Comment: Leila , estou o dia todo fazendo e acho que "consegui" , só que o problema é que agora os vetores estão invertidos ,  ele ta meio que aleatório mas acho que ta correto , tenta dar uma olhada , fiz um novo upload: https://ideone.com/zFMqQ5

Comment: fiz com números no papel e deu o mesmo resultado , só que em ordens diferentes :s

Comment: e respondendo sua pergunta , a loja1[100] vai receber 100 quantidade vendida de 100 produtos ,  se eu cadastrar 1 produto vai pro 0 a quantidade vendida dele

Comment: vou excluir o tópico , ninguém chegou a nenhuma conclusão né